# Backgroundworker works on development machine not workstations

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, backgroundworker

Have a weird issue. Have some long running processes. Basically creates many charts and then opens as PDF. When I run from within Visual Studio or via executable on the same machine it works perfectly.  When a user runs the application (Windows 7 64bit) the process still runs, but the UI freezes and the progress bar doesn't update until the process is complete.

Any ideas why this would/could occur?

Comment: You have to show us your code.

Comment: That would be difficult. It is a lot of code.  The weird thing is that it works 100% as expected from within Visual Studio or on the machine that it is built on.  I have never heard any OS dependencies.  It isn't like its broken it just run like it running on the same thread as the UI and simply locks the UI until it is complete.

Comment: But it's difficult to answer this question without seeing what you are doing.  Could be something with the PDF libraries you are probably referencing, or maybe you aren't using the background worker correctly — we don't know that because we can't see it.